# created_at date for xAxis highcharts

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

Below is the code that I now have. This gives me a 2 dimensional array (array of arrays) of the data I need which is perfect, because from what I can tell that's the best way to do what I am looking for with Highstock.

I think the last step I have to do is get it into the proper format for highstock: Date.UTC(2012, 9, 12)

I want it to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DkgVr/4/

Any idea how I can get the date to be like that?

The array right now looks like this: [[Thu, 13 Sep 2012, 215.0], [Wed, 12 Sep 2012, 211.0]]

Users Controller

```
@weight_items = Weight.order("date DESC").select('weights.content,  weights.date').all
```

Highstock

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'weight_chart',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 20,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Your Weight Over Time',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        scrollbar: {
          enabled: true
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },


        series: [{
            tickInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
            pointStart: <%= 3.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
            name: 'Weight',
            data: <%= weight_and_date_array = @weight_items.map{|row| [row.date.to_date, row.content.to_f] } %>

        }]
    }, 

    function(chart){

        // apply the date pickers
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#'+chart.options.chart.renderTo))
                .datepicker()
        },0)


      });
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: @Jugal sorry about that, I'm a n00b and didn't realize that was important. I just went through and accepted the correct answers to my questions. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Great, appreciated!!! Marking answers is as important as giving answers, it helps future visitors facing similar issues to know exactly which answer helped and hence save time of going through all submitted answers

Comment: @Hardik I actually switched to highstock last night, but it's still essentially the same question. I have datetime as the xAxis type, but I can't figure how to get an array of the "created_at" date and put it in there as the ticks on the xAxis.

Comment: @JugalThakkar pretty smart thinking. Will definitely keep in mind in the future!

Comment: @SteveQ: Can you provide code snippet for HighStock ?

Comment: @HardikMishra I added the code, let me know if you need more.

Comment: @HardikMishra do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: @HardikMishra I added the code for what I have and an example of what I'm looking to do. I think I'm pretty close, but I could use your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
       }
```

For HighStock. Also

```
{
    pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
    pointStart: <%= 3.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
    name: 'Weight',
    data: <%= Weight.pluck(:content).reverse %>
}
```

not required for Highstock. Keep `name` and `data` only.

Interval can be specified using `tickInterval` in the X Axis options.

EDIT:
After your edit, It seems that you are having problem in adding date in `HighStock` compliant format.

So, Add dates in UTC. Convert dates into UTC using Ruby, `HighStock` library will pickit automatically.

Comment: I took out the xAxis part. The pointInterval and Pointstart are needed to set default dates. 

I am going to play around with tickInterval and see if I can get the appropriate date to show up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Come back if any other help is required

Comment: I updated the code to what I currently have. I think I'm pretty close to solving this. I'd appreciate your help one more time if you could!

Comment: @SteveQ:When you add dates, Add it in UTC format. Check How can you convert date in  UTC using Ruby.(I don't know Ruby). And Do not completely Change the question. If its new problem you should create new question